# PHPMailer: random SMTP error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm in trouble with PHPMailer.
I have a PHP page that after doing all my functions should send an email with PHPMailer and SMTP Authentication.

Everything seems to work well except that sometimes, apparently at random, the code with

```
SMTPDebug = 1
```

returns

```
SMTP ->ERROR: DATA not accepted from server.
SMTP ERROR: DAta not accepted.
```

In 95 percent of time everything works and email arrive: it is possible that is a some kind of server problem that I can't fix? I use TMDHosting. Really don't know what to correct..
Here my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail -> AddReplyTo('mail@domain.it', 'SomeValue');
$mail -> SetFrom('mail@domain.it', $piede);
$subj = $piede . ' - Comment';
$mail -> Subject = $subject;
$mail -> SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail -> AddAddress($to);
$mail -> IsHTML();
$mail -> MsgHTML($message);
$mail -> IsSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> Host = 'mail.domain.com';
$mail -> Port = 2525;
$mail -> Username = 'mail@domain.com';
$mail -> Password = $mailPsw;
if ($mail -> Send()) {
echo 'OK';
} else {
echo $mail -> ErrorInfo;
}
```

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: is it just an error or email could not be sent?

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons for it...

one of them could be that the server is not behaving properly.

Now since it happens only a few times that means either the smtp server is trying to bottleneck your connections through throttling or rate limiting.

Dont try to spam or bombard the system with lots of mails, now a days the mailers are pretty strict with there norms.

Also try to run a script through telnet to send lots of mail and see if you still get any error.. a proper description of error from SMTP server is needed to analyze the situation.